# php Excel desactive scientific format

Tags: php, excel

I try to desactive scientific format in excel, i have see some examples with :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()...->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
```

but my excel in generate in header like this :

```
$class = 'product';
        $type = 'csv';
        $filename = "all_reviews_".$class."_".$_SESSION['AS_idWebsite']."_".date("Ymd").".".$type;

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=avis_'.date("dmYHis").'.csv');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        $tmpFile = file_get_contents($GENERAL_PATH_TMP_UPLOAD.$filename);
        echo chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($tmpFile, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
        exit;
```

its possible to do a "setFormatCode" in header ?

Comment: that is just an output script. either fix the file upon upload using the excel class, or load it with the excel class before the echo and fix it there

Answer (score 0):

You're working with a csv format file.... csv contains no formatting information at all, only raw data.... and if you open that file in MS Excel simply by double clicking on the file, then it will decide what formatting to use for numeric values itself.... if you use csv format, you cannot control this unless you explicitly open MS Excel and then use the "Import File" menu option to load the file